# why does my xbap crashes when loading from a web site that is routed through Sun IDM server?

Tags: wpf

I have a hybrid website, a mix of aspx and XBAPP resources, which is hosted on IIS6.0 on top of Windows 2003 server. We have a Sun IDM server for single-sign-on as there are multiple applications and a proxy, which rewrites the url. The website is hosted on a separate server and the IDM server on different machine. This is especially done to hide the actual resources being called from the IDM server. Every url hit goes to the IDM server and rewrites to the required resource server. Now the problem is when I call the website hosted server's url directly it works perfectly fine and XBAPP loads and run exactly as required but crashes when called through the IDM server. What I observed on Fiddler is that the moment the URL is called by the PresentationHost, there is a new session on the server and causes an authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

Look if you are redirecting to any self generated url. You should use a relative path everywhere to maintain the session. The proxy server might be impersonating the requests and the url. In such a case, a request to your absolute path might violate the impersonation and hence the loss of session.